# Интеграцию YooKassa в приложение react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Кто может что знает про интеграцию yookassa для react native expo на iOS & android ?

Читал офф документацию, в инете мало инфы тоже, особо не съехал, может есть примеры, кто сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста.